# Dependency injection IOption class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a class library where I want to access a Connectionstring from appsettings.json.

appsettings.json :

```
"DatabaseSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=.;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
```

In startup.cs I have the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings"));
    services.AddOptions();

    services.AddTransient<IConnectionOption, Class1>();
}
```

And in class library

IConnectionOption.cs

```
public interface IConnectionOption
{
    void ReadValue();
}
```

Class1.cs

```
public class Class1 : IConnectionOption
{
    private readonly DatabaseSettings test;

    public Class1(IOptions<DatabaseSettings> dbOptions)
    {
        test = dbOptions.Value;    
    }    

    public void ReadValue()
    {
        var r = test;
    }
}
```

Now from index.cshtml I want to Invoke the class Library Class1

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Class1 test = new Class1();
        test.ReadValue();
    }
}
```

But of course that doesnt work since there are no Constructor taking zero parameters, I don´t think I should add IOptions as an parameter. But how do I invoke the class library to read the connectionstring? (When I get this to work I will of course read data and return instead of the connectionstring). I have looked at several examples including [net core 2.1 Dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008843/net-core-2-1-dependency-injection)
But I don´t understand how to use the class library directly, Is it necessary to use an controller ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Dependency Injection but only halfway. This is what you are missing:

1. Register the service in the container (I'm going to assume a better name for `Class1`):

   ```
   services.AddScoped<IConnectionOption, DatabaseConnectionOption>();
   ```
2. Make the page receive the service:

   ```
   public class IndexModel : PageModel
   {
       private readonly IConnectionOption _IConnectionOption;

       public IndexModel(IConnectionOption iConnectionOption)
       {
           _IConnectionOption = iConnectionOption;
       }

       public void OnGet()
       {
           _IConnectionOption.ReadValue();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7):

If `DatabaseSettings` is accessible to the class library, there really is not much need for tightly coupling `Class1` library to `IOptions`, which is more framework related.

Ideally `Class1` can explicitly depend on `DatabaseSettings` via explicit constructor injection

```
public class Class1 : IConnectionOption {
    private readonly DatabaseSettings test;

    public Class1(DatabaseSettings settings) {
        test = settings;    
    }    

    public void ReadValue() {
        var r = test;
        //...
    }
}
```

then in `Startup`, the dependency can be extract from configuration and registered with the DI container

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    var settings = Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings").Get<DatabaseSettings>();
    services.AddSingleton<DatabaseSettings>(settings);    
    services.AddTransient<IConnectionOption, Class1>();
}
```

That way when ever `Class1` is resolved, the container will know how to inject the `DatabaseSettings` dependency.

Another option could have also been to use the factory delegate

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    var settings = Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings").Get<DatabaseSettings>();
    services.AddTransient<IConnectionOption, Class1>(_ => new Class1(settings));
}
```

That way, when the `IndexModel` depends on `IConnectionOption` for injection.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel {
    private readonly IConnectionOption connectionOption;

    public IndexModel(IConnectionOption iConnectionOption) {
        connectionOption = iConnectionOption;
    }

    public void OnGet() {
        connectionOption.ReadValue();
        //...
    }
}
```

the proper dependency will be injected when the page model is initialized.

Comment: Amen to not depending on `IOptions<T>`. But why register `DatabaseSettings` as transient? Why not as singleton? It's never going to change.

Comment: @Steven fixed. It really should have been singleton. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: A somewhat neater way of registering your settings class, which avoids the ugly `GetSection(<string>)` and has the added benefit of hot reloading the settings if they change during execution:

`services.AddTransient(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<DatabaseSettings>>().CurrentValue);`

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once! Excellent answer!